# How to troubleshoot login process to the OneDrive Business/Corporate?

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth, azure-active-directory, onedrive

For a two days I can't do login to get authorization code for the app.

During the login process, the authentication endpoint says nothing useful, for e.g. unauthorized user or client application or else. It's just redirect me to the https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf

Here is actual login url that I use: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=1dc49e01-ef07-4f66-9413-2ad70401b8c9&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Foauth.html
as described in documentation https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/aad_oauth.htm#step-1-log-in-and-get-an-authorization-code. 
This is real client id and the application was registered as describe here https://dev.onedrive.com/app-registration.htm#register-your-app-for-onedrive-for-business

Could anyone help me with this challenge?

Comment: The authentication endpoint is redirecting you to itself? Are you absolutely sure? I've never seen behaviour like this.

Comment: @juunas, yes. It does redirect to itself without any notifications.

Comment: @juunas, i have update. Seems like it's POST request to the https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf